# How do I mount a GoPro Hero 7 via USB in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, mount, camera, mtp

When I connect my GoPro Hero 7 camera via USB I see it in Files as HERO7, but when I click on it, it either mounts and says Folder is empty. Or the USB connected message on the camera appears and disappears and Files show the error

```
Unable to open MTP device usb: 002, 015).
```

I've tried different cables and ports.

Help!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when I used USB-C to USB-C cable. Once I switched to USB 3.0 - USB-C cable everything was back to normal. I also had gMTP installed, but I am not sure if it had any impact.

Comment: Switching to a USB 3.0 - USB-C cable worked for me also

Comment: weirdly, i have the exact reverse. None of my USB 3.0 - USB C cables are working on ubuntu, however the USB-C to USB-C seems fine.

Answer (score 4):

For GoPro Hero 8, go to *Preferences* → *Connections* → *USB Connection* → *MTP*.

Comment: Works for GoPro Hero 9 as well. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me on a Hero 9 after installing gMTP.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the Settings button on the side of the camera made it visible to my Linux system.

Here is what the link to my GoPro folder looks like, if this helps in any way:

```
mtp://GoPro_HERO7_C3281328889740/GoPro MTP Client Disk Volume/DCIM/100GOPRO/
```